Mapstruct 1.5.x : Mapping parameter of type Map<?,?> generates issue
Expected behavior
Mapstruct should generate implementation of Mapper at compilation. Version 1.4.2 doesn't have this issue.
Actual behavior
When a mapping method has a parameter of type Map<>, it throws an error at compilation.
This is my source code :
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
   <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
</dependency>

public class DestinationTO {
...
    private String arg1;
    private String someField;
...
}

public class SourceTO {
...
    private String someField;
...
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",
    injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR
)
public interface Arg1TOMapper {
...
    @Mapping(target = "arg1", ignore = true)
    DestinationTO mapSource(SourceTO source,
                               ...
                               Map<String, String> arg1,
                               ...);

    @AfterMapping
    default void mapArg1(final SourceTO source,
                               ...
                               final Map<String, String> arg1,
                               ...
                               @MappingTarget final DestinationTO destination ) {
...

Note: SourceTO doesn't contain arg1 attribute
At compilation it generates the following error :

Several possible source properties for target property "arg1".

Note : This only happens at version 1.5.x, version 1.4.2 compilates and generates source without a problem.
Steps to reproduce the problem
I use maven :
mvn clean install
MapStruct Version
1.5.5.Final
